# Tags to kill: "vectors"

Tags: discussion, tagging

I just retagged two questions containing the tag [vectors].  This is a useless tag.  It's like making a tag [elements-of-a-group].  Kill it whenever you see it from now on.  Good hunting.

Comment: I guess I don't understand why it's a useless tag. Can you elaborate a little more?

Comment: Any topic tagged [vectors] can more properly be tagged as [linear-algebra] or [calculus] depending on the topic.

Comment: This is a good point.

Comment: I suppose so. But the person asking might not realize that, and if they're searching for "vector" then having "vector" as a tag might eliminate unnecessary duplicate questions.